# Xamarin forms, DataTemplate vs Custom Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I have to add some elements inside a `ViewCell`. To do this I can choose between 2 aproaches:

1- Use `DataTemplate` to build the layout.

2- Use Custom Renderers.

I am trying to understand the difference between this two aproaches in situations like this.

When should I use a `DataTemplate`?

When should I use a Custom Renderer?

Comment: Why do you think those are the two approaches?  Use a DataTemplate.  A Custom Renderer only applies if you need platform specific UI that is not available via the standard Forms controls.

Comment: Microsoft manual for Custom Renderer does not use it for platform specific. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell Thanks for the answer. I will keep going with the DataTemplate.

Comment: huh - that doesn't strike me as a very helpful article.  But regardless, use a DataTemplate unless there is some specific problem that can only be solved with a Custom Renderer

Comment: and, I'll add that you should probably use a CollectionView instead of a ListView, which has eliminated the need for the *Cell classes

Comment: Thanks Jason. If you want you can write the answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) said:

> A Custom Renderer only applies if you need platform specific UI that
> is not available via the standard Forms controls.

So, we should use a DataTemplate always that we can layout the elements and we don't need nothing specific from any platform to behave or be drawn like we want.

In the other hand, we should use custom renderers if we need platform specific UI that we can't layout with the standard Forms controls.

Comment: I have to wait 1 day to accept it because it is answered by me. Thanks Wendy:)